# Advanced Google Custom Search: Filter using Labels from API Request

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search, get-request

**Problem:** I want to filter google custom search results (by label) directly from the API request.

**Example:** Say I have 3 websites in my search, and I want to query the term "bolt"

1. www.weather.com (Label="weather")
2. www.jamaicanSprinters.com (Label="athletes")
3. www.homeDepot.com (Label="tools")

I want my GCS API request to **only** return results from the Home Depot URL (Or at least **rank those results above** all other results).  How can I go about doing this directly through my API request?

**Pseudo-Example API Call request** to show the type of functionality I want:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=query**&label=LABEL**

The link below shows how I want to filter things, but I want to do it programatically through the API call, not by clicking a button.

https://support.google.com/customsearch//answer/2631064?hl=en&ctx=topic&topic=2642564

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @boardrider Thanks, I edited my question.  Is it more along the lines of what it should look like now?